# Missing the context menu showing verify and/or assert commands for recording with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

For a long time I have been using Selenium IDE to record and playback web applications for test purposes. Normally when I build a script, for each new page I would right click on a unique piece of text and select the command wait to ensure that when playing back Selenium doesn't move on until that page has loaded.

For some reason when I now right click the command context menu does appear in my list.

Since then downloaded the latest version of IDE but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the answer above, I rolled back to the previous version of Firefox (50.1.0) and I got the command context menu back. It's not a real fix, but it allows me to use the feature for now at least.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [FlowControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/flow-control/) Plugin and it should work again.

I found this workaround in the relating issue at: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3434#issuecomment-277039347

Another solution is to downgrade your firefox version to FF50 or prior.

Comment: I faced the same problem with FF 53. I have downgraded to FF 51 and It works well for me now.