# Missing Selenium IDE context items

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to get started with Selenium using a Lynda tutorial, and I can’t get Selenium's context menu’s items to appear (screenshot below).

Is there anything I'm missing, or that is incompatible? [The only other solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957515/why-am-i-missing-the-context-menu-showing-verify-and-or-assert-commands-for-reco) has no solution except a comment to roll back to an older version of Firefox.

- OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
- Java v8 update 121
- Firefox Developer Edition 53.0a2 (2017-02-09)
- Firefox 51.0.1
- Selenium IDE 2.9.1

In the screenshot below, you'll see the bottom divider line, below which should be the Selenium items.

[image: Missing Selenium IDE context items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context menu items should be there without any additional actions as long as Selenium IDE is running.

I think one of the last FireFox updates broke some Selenium IDE features. For example Select and Find buttons stopped working for me recently. They will probably fix it but I can not say when it'll happen.

If you really want to get those right-click options, I suppose you could install older FireFox version.

The other option is probably to try and finds way around it (but this may be a notable departure from the tutorial). For example you can click on the object to record it as a simple click and then edit Command part to get whatever you desire.
[That's just a sample of editing Selenium IDE command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpg3H.png)